# What are the asterisks on some Team Services menu items?

Tags: azure-devops

When I access my Team Services account in a browser, some menu items have an asterisk at the end of their name. In this image you can see 2 examples of them: "Wiki" and "Work Items".

What does that asterisk mean?

[image]

Comment: I would be very curious to hear from the downvoter what's wrong with this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a preview feature that you can turn on/off from Preview feature menu.

More information: [View and add work items using the Work Items page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/view-add-work-items)

Answer (score 0):

These are preview features/hubs which aren't released in general availability.

Comment: What do you mean by "general availability"? Are them visible only for some users? Or are they more like the "Documentation Beta" that took place on StackOverflow in these months?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus I think they are visible for all users, but you can disable some of them.