# How do I make sure all changes are saved to Test Plans in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: testing, azure-devops

I'm noticing the asterisk next to Test Plans in my view on Visual Studio Team Services. It shows next to the the text in the same manner it shows for items without saved changes. I want to remove the asterisk.

I made sure existing Test Plans were Saved and Closed. Even closed and reopened VSTS. I made sure to all switches were off from the Preview feature menu as suggested by the similar question below.

["What are the asterisks on some Team Services menu items?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362131/what-are-the-asterisks-on-some-team-services-menu-items)

[Asterisk next to Test Plans in Team Services.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfkOp.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the asterisks on some Team Services menu items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362131/what-are-the-asterisks-on-some-team-services-menu-items)

Comment: I indicated that question is similar. This is specifically directed at Test Plans. I also indicated that the quoted question's answer(s) does not resolve this.

Comment: Not every preview feature can be disabled.

Comment: That'll help me rephrase the question. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielMann the answer provided by Maria has the kind of focus on Test Plans the cited question wouldn't achieve. Consider removing the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because we use **new Test Plans hub** to manage VSTS test plans now.

> Introducing the new hub for Test Plans! Not only can you add, edit,
>   and delete plans from this page but also find and favorite plans
>   across your team and the project. We pioneered this type of experience
>   in Dashboards, Queries, and Plans. This is another step to bring this
>   consistency across the product.

More details, you can refer the release note for [Manage test plans using the new Test Plans hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/may-07-vsts#manage-test-plans-using-the-new-test-plans-hub).

Comment: On the release note there is mention of New Test Plan Experience preview feature. That does not show under Preview Features neither "for me", nor "for this account". Where do I go from here?

Comment: @00Zero This feature has already been released on May 7th 2018, and using asterisk for the new Test Plans hub aim to distinguish with the old Test plans hub.

Comment: @00Zero If the answer helps you for the confusion, can you mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar confusion.

Comment: In the end, and based on the replies to my submitted issue to MS, there was a bug   pertaining the user interface on Test Plans view. MS had rolled out the new interface as indicated in Marina's answer. Items I was working on were properly saved.